# yum install failed i686 x86_64

Tags: redhat, glibc, yum

my version is 6.10 oracle linux

it is trying to istall both x86_64 and i686 packages
i am trying to install glibc package manually as it fails during my puppet run with exact same error as below:

```
yum install glibc-2.12-1.192.el6.i686
Loaded plugins: pulp-profile-update, security, ulninfo
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.12-1.192.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-common = 2.12-1.192.el6 for package: glibc-2.12-1.192.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so for package: glibc-2.12-1.192.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so(NSSRAWHASH_3.12.3) for package: glibc-2.12-1.192.el6.i686
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.12-1.192.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-common = 2.12-1.192.el6 for package: glibc-2.12-1.192.el6.i686
---> Package nss-softokn-freebl.i686 0:3.14.3-23.3.el6_8 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: glibc-2.12-1.192.el6.i686 (nap_latest)
           Requires: glibc-common = 2.12-1.192.el6
           Installed: glibc-common-2.12-1.212.0.1.el6.x86_64 (@OL6Latest-x86_64/6.9)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.212.0.1.el6
           Available: glibc-common-2.12-1.80.el6.x86_64 (nap_ol_base)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.80.el6
           Available: glibc-common-2.12-1.107.el6_4.5.x86_64 (nap_latest)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.107.el6_4.5
           Available: glibc-common-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64 (nap_latest)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.132.el6
           Available: glibc-common-2.12-1.132.el6_5.2.x86_64 (nap_latest)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.132.el6_5.2
           Available: glibc-common-2.12-1.132.el6_5.4.x86_64 (nap_latest)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.132.el6_5.4
           Available: glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64 (nap_latest)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.149.el6
           Available: glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64 (nap_latest)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.149.el6_6.5
           Available: glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6_6.9.x86_64 (nap_latest)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.149.el6_6.9
           Available: glibc-common-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.x86_64 (nap_latest)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.166.el6_7.3
           Available: glibc-common-2.12-1.166.el6_7.7.x86_64 (nap_latest)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.166.el6_7.7
           Available: glibc-common-2.12-1.192.el6.x86_64 (nap_latest)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.192.el6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

any ideas? has anyone seen this previously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot install `glibc-2.12-1.192.el6.i686` and `glibc-2.12-1.212.0.1.el6.x86_64` in parallel.  You will have to downgrade to `glibc-2.12-1.192.el6.x86_64`.  With a proper repository configuration, this should work:

```
yum downgrade glibc-2.12-1.192.el6.x86_64
```

However, it is probably easier if you run `yum upgrade` and then simply install `glibc.i686`, without an explicit version.

(`2.12-1.212.0.1.el6` is a strange version, by the way.  Not sure what Oracle is doing there.)

Answer (score 1):

ok here is what i did to get this to work:

```
yum -y downgrade glibc glibc-common

yum install -y glibc.i686   glibc-devel.i686  glibc-devel.x86_64 glibc-headers.x86_64
```

you should have something like this:

```
glibc.i686                       
glibc.x86_64                     
glibc-common.x86_64              
glibc-devel.i686                 
glibc-devel.x86_64               
glibc-headers.x86_64
```

if you still have problems check your repos